# iOS Core Data managedObjectContext: No know class method for selector

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Probably something simple, but none of my searches are getting me what I need.

I am using Core Data in my app to manage players and matches for a game.  My core data stack is completely generic and in my AppDelegate.  I am trying to make a helper class that will return an Entity (Player) based on a search string.  When I try to wire up core data, I am getting this error when setting up my fetchRequest.

No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext'

here's the code...
PlayerSearch.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Player.h"

@interface PlayerSearch : NSObject

+ (Player *)searchForPlayerWithID:(NSString*)playerID;

@end
```

PlayerSearch.m

## import "PlayerSearch.h"

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface PlayerSearch()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation PlayerSearch

-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext{
return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}

+ (Player *)searchForPlayerWithID:(NSString*)playerID
{

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

...

return player;
}
@end
```

The error is showing up when I set the fetchRequest.entity's context.  This is exactly how I am setting the context in my view controllers throughout the app and it works fine there...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `searchForPlayerWithID:` method is a class method and you are trying to call an instance method (`managedObjectContext`) on `self` from within that class method.

You can fix this by changing your `managedObjectContext` method to be a class method:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

Comment: He would then also need to modify the call site to not call self but rather the class name (or maybe [self class])